# How to explicitly pass the "AzureAd" details to AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi method for token validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, access-token, microsoft-identity-platform

I am using `Microsoft.Identity.Web` library to validate the token in my .Net Core Web API.

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
        ------------

    services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration);

        ------------
}
```

but as per the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-app-configuration), I need to pass the **AzureAd** (an object that will contain tenantId, ClientId, Domain, Instance, etc) object to `AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi` method through IConfiguration instance. As of now, this method tries to load this object from local appsetings.json file. I want to pass these details explicitly to the method `AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi` as we are not storing any key-values in local appsettings.json file (all are coming through Consul and Vault).

I tried to override the Configuration object but was unable to do.

How do I pass this AzureAd object to `AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi` method so that it can validate the token and what is missing?

**UPDATE**:
Hey.. I managed to pass the values explicitly.

```cs
Action<JwtBearerOptions> configureJwtBearerOptions = Test1;
static void Test1(JwtBearerOptions t1)
{
    t1.Audience = $"{appSettings.adCredentials.Instance}/{appSettings.adCredentials.TenantId}";
    t1.TokenValidationParameters.ValidAudiences = new string[] {
        appSettings.adCredentials.ClientId,
        $"api://{appSettings.adCredentials.ClientId}"
    };
}

Action<MicrosoftIdentityOptions> configureMicrosoftIdentityOptions = Test2;
static void Test2(MicrosoftIdentityOptions t2)
{
    t2.TenantId = appSettings.adCredentials.TenantId;
    t2.ClientId = appSettings.adCredentials.ClientId;
    t2.Instance = appSettings.adCredentials.Instance;
    t2.Domain = appSettings.adCredentials.Domain;
    t2.ClientSecret = appSettings.adCredentials.ClientSecret;
}

IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(configureJwtBearerOptions, configureMicrosoftIdentityOptions) ;
```

Now when I am calling the API from postman its throwing the error along with status code 500:

> System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/{tenantId}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
> ---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20807: Unable to retrieve document from: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/{tenantId}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration'. HttpResponseMessage: 'StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent

How can one properly resolve this?

Comment: I think it has an overload that you can use that allows you to specify a function that takes the options. That allows you to set values there how you want.

Comment: Can you please reply with example as I am new to this entirely

Comment: @samirjamadar you need to replace the {tenantId} with your directoryId

Answer (score 4):

for .net 6

```
builder.Services
.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
```

Answer (score 1):

overload your `AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi` with a `"AzureAd"` after `Configuration`

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration, "AzureAd");
```

Comment: He's asking how to do this if there is no IConfiguration available. I have the same issue, we use our own config format and need to pass these values explicitly.